# Preset filter in Flask-Admin index view, but let user change filtering conditions

Tags: python, flask-admin

I need to apply a pre-defined filter in the Index View of a ModelView class, for example show 'Objects' that have 'Active == 1'. However, the user should be able to reset or modify the filtering conditions (she may want to see all 'Objects', etc.), so modifying the get_query() function is not the way.

I ended up using the following solution which just hardcodes the filter arguments if the user open a blank index view from a different referrer:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    column_filters = ['source', 'active']

    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        if len(request.args) == 0 and 
                not request.path in str(request.referrer):
            return redirect(request.path + '?flt2_7=1')
        else:
            return super(MyModelView, self).index_view()
```

Is there a better way to do the job?

One of the issues here is that changing filters list means having to change the redirect path